# How to pass url parameters on Post request in Netsuite Suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

In get request I have this Url

https://system.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=22&deploy=1&locationId=&vendorId=120&parentId=

When It is post request the url changes to

https://system.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl

and parameters are lost. How can I keep the prameter post request.

By post request I mean else part of the below code

```
if (request.getMethod() == 'GET' )
   {
       createUI(); // Just create the UI 

   }else{
       createUI(); // create UI and process the data in post request
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can still get the parameter values by using request.getParameter('locationid')